# Oracle query optimization for select

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

Below is my query and i want to know if any optimization is possible in this query or not ?

FYI, I have applied index on C_NUMBER , CA_NUMBER and D_TIMESTAMP column.

```
SELECT
  NAM, RSON, URL
FROM TM_CAM
WHERE C_NUMBER = A_C_NUMBER
  AND CA_NUMBER = A_CA_NUMBER
  AND (SYSTIMESTAMP) <= D_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY D_TIMESTAMP DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

There is a `ORDER BY` so i think its not good from a performance perspective.

I tried below but it has degraded performance.

```
SELECT
  NAM, RSON, URL
FROM TM_CAM
WHERE D_TIMESTAMP = (
  SELECT MAX(D_TIMESTAMP )
  FROM TM_CAM
  )
  AND C_NUMBER = A_C_NUMBER
  AND CA_NUMBER = A_CA_NUMBER
  AND (SYSTIMESTAMP) <= D_TIMESTAMP
```

Any inputs please ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve as your first and second queries do not give the same result? The second query is the equivalent of using `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` and not `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: ok thanks. I am trying to see if we can optimize the execution time of the first query.

Comment: Is it a single index spanning all 3 columns or 3 separate indices, each spanning a single column?

Comment: Such low timings (20~200 ms) also depend on the network transfer time, result output, query parsing etc depending on the way you measure performance. I don't think it is possible to accurately tune the query in such time frame

Comment: @knittl : 3 separate index

Comment: @astentx : I agree. Round trip network related point i have checked so its fine. I want how much we can optimized from oracle query execution perspective or something can be done with oracle db tuning etc

Comment: @VJS only a single index will be used per query. Make sure to have a single compound index which covers all 3 columns used in the where clause (and pay attention to the selectivity of each column).

Comment: And an addition to the previous comment: equality columns (`C_NUMBER` , `CA_NUMBER`) should be placed first for Oracle to be possible to perform range scan instead of skip scan. Then it would be able to locate an index subtree of interest by (relatively) fast equality search and then perform ascending or descending range scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting slows things down, that's for sure.

Your 1st query looks OK to me; how many rows are involved? What kind of optimization do you expect? I guess you're concerned about execution time; if so, how long does that query take? Did you check explain plan?

Meanwhile, try

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT nam,
              rson,
              url,
              ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY d_timestamp DESC) rn
         FROM tm_nam
        WHERE     c_number = a_c_number
              AND ca_number = a_ca_number
              AND SYSTIMESTAMP <= d_timestamp)
SELECT nam, rson, url
  FROM temp
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

or

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT nam, rson, url
           FROM tm_nam
          WHERE     c_number = a_c_number
                AND ca_number = a_ca_number
                AND SYSTIMESTAMP <= d_timestamp
       ORDER BY d_timestamp DESC)
SELECT nam, rson, url
  FROM temp
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. In table, we have around 1 million records but this sorting will happen on ~10000 records as it is filtered out due to c_number and ca_number. Yes, i am expecting optimization in execution time.  My observation is random. Mostly query takes ~10-20 ms but sometime its take more than 60 ms to 200 ms. I want it to be executed in less than 20 ms everytime.

Comment: Aha. So, it takes *sleepy blink of an eye*, while you'd want it to return result in *blink of an eye*. Personally, if that query affects end user, I doubt they are capable of seeing any difference between 20 and 100 miliseconds. If it affects some processing so that number of miliseconds is *multiplied* by a large number, then yes - I guess you'd want to make it faster.

Comment: ok thanks. BTW, As you suggested to try in answer, do you think it will help to reduce execution time ?

Comment: Try and see. I would, but I don't have your table nor data so I can't tell.

Comment: @Littlefoot `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` does exactly `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY <order by column>) <= 1` under the hood, see https://dbfiddle.uk/d6Lpzyat

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second queries are not the same as the second query is the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT NAM, RSON, URL
FROM   TM_CAM
WHERE  C_NUMBER     =  A_C_NUMBER
AND    CA_NUMBER    =  A_CA_NUMBER
AND    SYSTIMESTAMP <= D_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY D_TIMESTAMP DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

---

You could rewrite it using `ROWNUM`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT NAM, RSON, URL
  FROM   TM_CAM
  WHERE  C_NUMBER     =  A_C_NUMBER
  AND    CA_NUMBER    =  A_CA_NUMBER
  AND    SYSTIMESTAMP <= D_TIMESTAMP
  ORDER BY D_TIMESTAMP DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

But if you compare the execution plan you will probably find that Oracle uses very similar (if not identical) plans for `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`, filtering on `ROWNUM = 1` or for filtering on the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function so it is likely that you can pick whichever query is easiest to maintain and use that.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tfSAy8KR)